# how to make following changes ( table element styling)

Tags: html, css

In my mobile application, I have a in-box message and it's in table format:

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/cGGPC/)

HTML:

```
      <div>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="td1">
                        <img src="images/inbox_read.png" class="icon">
                    </td>
                    <td class="td2"><span>You have received a message</span>

                    </td>
                    <td class="td3"><span class="date">13/2/2014  20:02:01</span>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="seperator-gradient"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="td1">
                        <img src="images/inbox_read.png" class="icon">
                    </td>
                    <td class="td2"><span>You have received a message</span>

                    </td>
                    <td class="td3"><span class="date">13/2/2014  20:02:01</span>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="seperator-gradient"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="td1">
                        <img src="images/inbox_read.png" class="icon">
                    </td>
                    <td class="td2"><span>You have received a message</span>

                    </td>
                    <td class="td3"><span class="date">13/2/2014  20:02:01</span>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="seperator-gradient"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
            TABLE {
                width: 100%;
                text-align: left;
                padding: 6px 10px 10px;
            }
            TABLE .td1 {
                width: 30px;
            }
            TABLE .td2 {
                width: 154px;
            }
            TABLE .td3 {
                text-align: right;
                background-image: url("../images/more_arrow.png");
                background-position: 100% 10px;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: 10px 15px;
                width: 110px;
            }
            TABLE .sicon {
                height: 10px;
                width: 10px;
            }
            .date {
                color: #2aa8dc;
                float: right;
                position: relative;
                top: -8px;
                font-size: 12px;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }
            .seperator-gradient {
                width: 100%;
                height: 1px;
                border-bottom: background: #c4c4c4;
                /* Old browsers */
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 0%, #e3e3e3 10%, #b8b8b8 50%, #e3e3e3 90%, #fcfcfc 100%);
                /* FF3.6+ */
                background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #ffffff), color-stop(10%, #e3e3e3), color-stop(50%, #b8b8b8), color-stop(90%, #e3e3e3), color-stop(100%, #fcfcfc));
                /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 0%, #e3e3e3 10%, #b8b8b8 50%, #e3e3e3 90%, #fcfcfc 100%);
                /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
                background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 0%, #e3e3e3 10%, #b8b8b8 50%, #e3e3e3 90%, #fcfcfc 100%);
                /* Opera 11.10+ */
                background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 0%, #e3e3e3 10%, #b8b8b8 50%, #e3e3e3 90%, #fcfcfc 100%);
                /* IE10+ */
                background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 0%, #e3e3e3 10%, #b8b8b8 50%, #e3e3e3 90%, #fcfcfc 100%);
                /* W3C */
                filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#fcfcfc', GradientType=1);
                /* IE6-9 */
            }
```

You can shrink your browser size to make it phone's width. Then:

I'd like to make the second td's message not to break to a newline on phone's width(320px), how to achieve this without changing the table's structure:

```
<td class="td2"><span>You have received a message</span>

 </td>
```

[image]

keep all the table width, just make the message show in one line even it exceeds boundary between td2 and td3...is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

So you want it to be cut off? Overlap the date/time? What?

`TABLE` in your CSS should be lowercase;

and I do not believe `width` works well on elements (e.g. `td`'s) that are `display: table-cell;

**SO**

Change:

```
.td2 {
    width: 154px;
}
```

**TO**

```
.td2 span {
    display: block;
    background-color: green; /* used for demonstration purposes */
    width: 200px;/* 154px isn't enough */
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. What I'd like to achieve is, is it possible to make the message to extend it's boundary to td3?

Comment: It also answers your question! ;)

Comment: I need to keep the width of td3 ( it required more space to be displayed in one line)

Comment: That is all your own design decisions!  But when you tested my answer it did what you were asking for, correct?